# Getting directory of pyqt open file in a try/except (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system, filesystems, pyqt4

I have a gui script that has a button for users to click and select a file for running some processing on. I want to create a save path which is the same directory as the original file was opened from so that the saved file is saved back there.

I use a try/except in the code in case of errors and I just can't get the savepath code to work. It's breaking the try/except so it's always going to the exception.   I know it's something to do with the format of the os and the pyqt path/filename but I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it?

It's  currently saving working directory unless I put a second button to choose the output location which seems pointless when the users will save in the same location as the input file every time, but this will be a different folder location each time so I can't hard code the path.

This is my code:

```
    try:
       self.inputfile = open(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open File", "", "txt files (*.txt)"),'r+')
       self.save_path = os.path.dirname(self.inputfile)

       with self.inputfile as f:
          for line in f:
          #....do some processing

    except:
        #show an error message#
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try moving the save_path and the with clause outside of the try/except and see if that helps... will post back if it does. Im probably misunderstanding something here somewhere...

Comment: Never mind I sorted I had to manipulate the path output because of the qfile it was incorrect...  so I had to split the string after the q-file information. But if anyone has a better way of dealing with the q-files (I suspect even my nomenclature is incorrect here) please say.